# How do I untar a file skipping the beginning of the directory structure

Tags: unix, archive, tar

I created tar archives with an absolute path to save the files.

```
/home/mydir/dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.dat
/home/mydir/dir1/dir2/dir3/file2.dat
/home/mydir/dir1/dir2/dir3/file3.dat
```

I would like to untar these archives skipping the beginning of the directory structure `/home/mydir/dir1`. My files should be restored in any directory with this structure :

```
dir2/dir3/file1.dat
dir2/dir3/file2.dat
dir2/dir3/file3.dat
```

**How can I do this with the tar command or another way ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tar -xf /for/untar/your/filename.extension --strip=3 path/to/which/you/wish/to/extract
```